# "At the time" vs "at that time"

Tags: phrases, sentence

Examples:

> I met Monica a year ago. **At that time,** I was living in New Work,
>   in a middle-sized apartment overlooking the Mississippi River.
>
> I met Monica a year ago. **At the time,** I was living in New Work, in
>   a middle-sized apartment overlooking the Mississippi River.

Do they mean the same? Which is more appropriate for the example above?

Comment: 'Yes' and 'either'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the examples you provided they basically mean the same thing. *That* points to the physical time *a year ago*, while *the* simply refers to the known, mentioned time, which is also *a year ago*. So in your case they both can be used with no difference in meaning.